# makefile can't find include file path even with -I flag

Tags: makefile, include, include-path

Compiling with Makefile tells me that it can't find path to some include files.
Here's my directory layout:

```
build (empty directory)
include (directory)
    tpu_uarch (directory)
        buffer.hpp common.hpp controller.hpp cpu.hpp
        dram.hpp interconnect.hpp mmu.hpp unit.hpp weightfetcher.hpp
obj (directory)
    tpu_uarch (empty directory)
src (directory)
    test_mmu.cpp test_tile.cpp
    buffer.cpp common.cpp controller.cpp cpu.cpp
    dram.cpp interconnect.cpp mmu.cpp weightfetcher.cpp
Makefile
```

And here's what `Makefile` looks like:

```
TESTTILE := ./build/testtile.exe
TEST3 := ./build/test3.exe

CC := g++
CPP_SUFFIX := cpp

INCLUDE_DIR := -I./include
SRC_DIR = ./src
OBJ_DIR = ./obj

CFLAGS := -g -Wall -std=c++11
LDFLAGS :=
LIBS :=

# all sources
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.$(CPP_SUFFIX))
SRC += $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/**/*.$(CPP_SUFFIX))

# objects
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(CPP_SUFFIX), $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC))

DIR = $(dir $(OBJ))

# executables
testtile: dir $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(TESTTILE) $(LIBS)

test3: dir $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(TEST3) $(LIBS)

dir:
    mkdir -p $(DIR)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(CPP_SUFFIX)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    rm $(TESTTILE)
    rm $(TEST3)
```

When I write `make test3` in command line, I get the following error.

```
mkdir -p ./obj/ ./obj/ ./obj/tpu_uarch/ ./obj/tpu_uarch/ ./obj/tpu_uarch/ ./obj/tpu_uarch/ ./obj/tpu_uarch/ ./obj/tpu_uarch/ ./obj/tpu_uarch/ ./obj/tpu_uarch/
g++ -I./include -g -Wall -std=c++11 -c src/test_tile.cpp -o obj/test_tile.o
src/test_tile.cpp:1:22: fatal error: common.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'obj/test_tile.o' failed
make: *** [obj/test_tile.o] Error 1
```

In all of the `*.cpp` files, they add include files like `#include "common.hpp"` without adding directory information. As I understand, adding the `-I` flag in `INCLUDE_DIR` should solve problems of finding the include files.

I've checked earlier that the code compiles if I put all `.cpp` and `.hpp` files in one directory and type `g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 -o test3.exe buffer.cpp common.cpp controller.cpp cpu.cpp dram.cpp interconnect.cpp mmu.cpp weightfetcher.cpp test_mmu.cpp` in the command line interface.

In making test3.exe, `test_tile.cpp` is not used but I don't think that should be a problem.

Is there something I'm missing or should look into?

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're telling `g++` to look in `./include` but, according to the directory hierarchy shown, `common.hpp` is actually under `./include/tpu_uarch`.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks! Solved my problem! Could you post it again as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Moved from comments]

You're telling `g++` to look in `./include` but, according to the directory hierarchy shown, `common.hpp` and the other headers are actually under `./include/tpu_uarch`.  You need...

```
INCLUDE_DIR := -I./include/tpu_uarch
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who came to find an answer... Even after fixing the issue that G.M. pointed out, I still had some minor issues. (Such as conflict in that both test files include the `main()` function, etc.)

After that, I managed to fix the code to work.
Here is the **working version** of Makefile.

```
TESTTILE := ./build/testtile.exe
TESTMMU := ./build/testmmu.exe

CC := g++
CPP_SUFFIX := cpp

INCLUDE_DIR := -I./include/tpu_uarch
SRC_DIR = ./src
OBJ_DIR = ./obj
BUILD_DIR = ./build

CFLAGS := -g -Wall -std=c++11
LDFLAGS :=
LIBS :=

# all sources
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.$(CPP_SUFFIX))
SRC += $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/**/*.$(CPP_SUFFIX))

# objects
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(CPP_SUFFIX), $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC))

DIR = $(dir $(OBJ))

# for tests
TESTTILE_OBJ := ./obj/test_tile.o
TESTMMU_OBJ := ./obj/test_mmu.o

# executables
testtile: dir $(OBJ) $(TESTTILE_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(TESTTILE_OBJ) -o $(TESTTILE) $(LIBS)

testmmu: dir $(OBJ) $(TESTMMU_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(TESTMMU_OBJ) -o $(TESTMMU) $(LIBS)

dir:
    mkdir -p $(DIR)

obj/test_tile.o: $(BUILD_DIR)/test_tile.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(CFLAGS) -c ./build/test_tile.cpp -o ./obj/test_tile.o

obj/test_mmu.o: $(BUILD_DIR)/test_mmu.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(CFLAGS) -c ./build/test_mmu.cpp -o ./obj/test_mmu.o

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(CPP_SUFFIX)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    rm $(TESTTILE)
    rm $(TEST3MMU)
```

The directory topology is as follows:

```
build (directory)
    test_mmu.cpp test_tile.cpp
    testmmu.exe testtile.exe (executables created after running make)
include (directory)
    tpu_uarch (directory)
        buffer.hpp common.hpp controller.hpp cpu.hpp
        dram.hpp interconnect.hpp mmu.hpp unit.hpp weightfetcher.hpp
obj (directory, all contents here including directory are created after running make)
    tpu_uarch (directory)
        buffer.o common.o controller.o cpu.o
        dram.o interconnect.o mmu.o weightfetcher.o
    test_mmu.o
    test_tile.o
src (directory)
    tpu_uarch (directory)
        buffer.cpp common.cpp controller.cpp cpu.cpp
        dram.cpp interconnect.cpp mmu.cpp weightfetcher.cpp
Makefile
```

Hope this helps.